# Upload image to server from input type=file

Tags: javascript, html, image, file

I have a `<input type='file' />` in which the user can upload an image.
I want to save that image as a server file(let's say 'hello.jpg')
How can I do that using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just upload file with js? If so you can use this plugin https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: How can I use this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The server will need to run a backend that can accept form `POST` requests containing files you would like to upload. A common Javascript-based backend is the Node.js `express` module. The `formidible` module can be used to parse incoming file `POST` forms.

I would recommend building a proof-of-concept first to get an idea for all the technologies involved.

Here are some tutorials I found that would be relevant:

https://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/

https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/